# Context Free Grammar for unequal number of symbols

Tags: context-free-grammar, lexical, context-free-language

I'm aware of how it is possible to construct a context free grammar with the same number of two given elements ie. if we use {0,1}

```
S->SS
S->0S1
S->1S0
S->ε
```

I am however struggling to find a way to construct a grammar that has a given amount of one element more than another. ie. consistently two more 0s than 1s.
Does anyone have any ideas of how to construct such a grammar?

Comment: Yes, I do have an idea. Hint: two unequal sets are just two equal sets separated by multiple of one of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out a nice answer to this:

```
S->P0P0P
P->PP
P->0P1
P->1P0
P->ε
```

It should come up with a string of two more 0s than 1s, and can be easily extended to greater numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Edit : (corrected) Something like the following  forces to have at least one  0 more than 1's:

```
S->T0S | T0T
T->0T1T | 1T0T | ε
```

so now, it shouldn't be too hard to add one more 0 by repeating same pattern ...

doing so the following grammar answers the problem:

```
S->T0S | T0T
T->0T1T | 1T0T 
T->U0T | U0U
U->0U1U | 1U0U | ε
```

Comment: But what about the following:
0T   (begin), 
0TT (T->TT rule), 
000 (T->0 rule), 
Surely in this case you would break the rule?

Comment: you're right ! we should not change the last rule and rewrite the first rules

Comment: thanks! surely you could end up with 000 though by going from T0T, then substituting 0 in for T?

Comment: yes, if we end by ε instead of 0, we have the language with at least one more 0 than 1's so shouldn't be too hard to force a new 0 ... i'll edit